# Is there a way to make this code insert all the current data in the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

What i want is to insert all of the data in all rows and columns from my datagrid view into my database. I am not getting any error but this is not working not inserting any value in my database.

```
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    for (int i = 0; i < dgEdit.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       DateTime ds = DateTime.Now;
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Tb BL_Attendance(Course, Subject, 
       Year, Section, Name, Room, SeatNo, Status, Date) VALUES('" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "', '" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "', '" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "', '" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "', '" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + "', '" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value + "', '" + 
       dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value + "', @Date) ";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ds);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
     MessageBox.Show("Updated! please check the report", "Save", 
     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
     con.Close();
```

I was expecting this to insert all of my datagrid values into a table

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: In one place you have `dgEdit`, in another `dgvAtt`. Are you wrong?

Comment: Do NOT use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prototype is correct but you did one mistake, `dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value` return an Object to must convert it to `ToString()` or the column data in your table that could match with.

> Let's say this is my form

[image: let's say this my form]

**I Created a table 'Person'**
[image: Person]

> Code Source

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvAtt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                string Query = "INSERT INTO Person (idPerson, fullnamePerson) VALUES (" + dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + ",'" + dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "')";
                cmd.CommandText = Query;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Updated! please check the report", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

---

**Don't write any Parameters because this will give you an exception.**

Comment: I tried using this 
dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() and this
dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString()

still not working. And this dgvAtt.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Text seems to give red underline in the Text part

Comment: @DietherNoche i updated my answer, i think now it's working.

Comment: Yes it is now working but it is inserting the data in my database way too many. not exactly how many is in the current database

Answer (score 2):

The logic below tries to be as close as possible to your implementation, but taking into account best practices when dealing with database connections:

```
// You will need the following namespaces:
// using System;
// using System.Data;
// using System.Data.SqlClient;
// using System.Windows.Forms;

var connectionString = "Your SQL Server connection string";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO Tbl_Attendance (Course, Subject, Year, Section, Name, Room, SeatNo, Status, Date) " +
        "VALUES (@Course, @Subject, @Year, @Section, @Name, @Room, @SeatNo, @Status, @Date)";

    var courseParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Course", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    var subjectParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subject", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    var yearParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    var sectionParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Section", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    var nameParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    var roomParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Room", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    var seatNoParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SeatNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    var statusParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

    var dateParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    dateParam.Value = DateTime.Now;

    // If you are going to insert a lot of records, it's advised to call the Prepare method on your SqlCommand.
    // Un-comment the line below if you want to see how this behaves.
    // cmd.Prepare();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgEdit.Rows)
    {
        courseParam.Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
        subjectParam.Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
        yearParam.Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
        sectionParam.Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
        nameParam.Value = row.Cells[4].Value;
        roomParam.Value = row.Cells[5].Value;
        seatNoParam.Value = row.Cells[6].Value;
        statusParam.Value = row.Cells[7].Value;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

MessageBox.Show("Updated! please check the report", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Reason behind the changes:

- When possible, instantiate and open your SqlConnection connection inside a
  `using` statement. This will ensure that your connection is always
  closed (disposed) when you are done with it in the scope.
- **Always use parameters in your queries when interacting with any external input**, to avoid Bobby's mom exploit! (https://xkcd.com/327/).
  This will ensure that your code is not susceptible to SQL injection.
  As you can see, I added some parameters, but because you didn't
  provide your table schema I made then `VARCHAR(50)` with the
  exception of the `@Date` one where it's clear that you are saving a
  `System.DateTime`. Please feel free to change the `SqlDbType.VarChar`
  to the correct type where needed.
- I moved the call to `MessageBox.Show` outside the `using` scope so it doesn't interfere with the connection disposal.

Another enhancement that you could do to this logic is implementing the use of the `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` class (you must add a reference to System.Transactions.dll), to ensure that if there's an error during any of the inserts, nothing gets `committed` to the database.