# Read unicode characters from text or richtext field

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to work out how to read and store odd unicode characters from a text field or rich text field into a string to then update in an SQL database.

I think I have the SQL side of things sorted out however I can't work out the user input side.

I have a text box or rich text box (tried both) on a form where the user inputs  [image: refer attached]
into the field, and they can input put it ok, but how do I retrieve it to send to SQL?

A string variable just converts it to <104cfu/g.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I put the following example together to help you spot the issue that you may have in your code, and the reason why it isn't saving the unicode string into your table.

This example will save unicode text into the `dbo.MyTable` table, which has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    MyColumn NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

And this logic will insert a record into the `dbo.MyTable` table with the text from `textbox1.Text`:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (var cm = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cm.CommandText = "INSERT dbo.MyTable (MyColumn) VALUES (@MyText)";

        // Assuming textBox1 is your textbox...
        cm.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@MyText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1) { Value = textBox1.Text }
            );

        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

Based on your comment below, I made the following changes to your code around the `SqlCommand` to use parameters instead of string concatenation, I explained why this is bad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502151/is-there-a-way-to-make-this-code-insert-all-the-current-data-in-the-database/54507195#54507195); The code below will save your unicode text into your table as expected and will be safe:

```
SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ProductTestSpecifications set Specification = @Specification where ProductID = @ProductID and TestID = @TestID", con);

// When building your SqlCommand, always use parameters if you are interacting with external input, this will protect you against SQL injection.
ins.Parameters.Add("@Specification", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = myRichText.Text;

// Im assuming ProductID and TestID are System.Int32, if not, please change SqlDbType.Int to the appropriate type.
ins.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ProductID;
ins.Parameters.Add("@TestID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TestID;

try
{
    ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    result = ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my column is NVARCHAR(MAX) and my code is:

SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ProductTestSpecifications set Specification = '" + myRichText.Text + "' where ProductID = " + ProductID + " and TestID = " + TestID, con);
try
   {
      ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
catch (Exception ex)
   {
      result = ex.Message.ToString();
   }

but it still saves without the "special" characters in SQL...

Comment: Hi @Dean. Please follow my example and use parameters for your query (for, Specification, ProductID and TestID), that will resolve the issue. The code that you just showed me is sensible to SQL injection attacks! I wrote about this in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54507195/2206145

Comment: Also, to explain why your code is striping out the unicode characters; in SQL server a `NVARCHAR` type literal must be preceded by `N`, eg. `N'My unicode text'`. You are not doing that there when you are concatenating `myRichText.Text`, therefore, SQL server is converting that to a `VARCHAR` type instead. Again, please don't do this, use parameters instead, you will be safe and your code will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the logic here in parameterised queries, makes more sense... but still does'nt save the value correctly. It sill stores in the DB as <104cfu/g with the 4 not being superscript.

Comment: @Dean, can you set a breakpoint in your code, copy the original value from `myRichText.Text` using the debugger and paste it here? The code I provided you must work, unless the value in `myRichText.Text` doesn't has that unicode character at all.

Comment: I worked out another way to do it... if I use the myRichText.Rtf value then I can get the reuslt I am after... the .Text property just doesn't hold the value in super/sub script...

Answer (score 1):

Switch from using the Text property of the RichTextBox to the Rtf property. It achieves the result I am after...

Thanks all

Comment: You would get your answer a lot quicker if you provided your sample code in your original question (there is edit button) instead of a comment somewhere else. Anyways welcome to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Well, .NET is unicode from the beginning, so it should be straightforward.

Make sure your database column collation is unicode as well (types such `nvarchar` or just collation itself that supports unicode characters).

It usually helps when you provide a sample of your code so that it's easier to find a problem.

Comment: You shouldn't be recommending `ntext` in 2019. It's been deprecated since *2005*...

Comment: I haven't noticed sql-server tag so I was making a reference in general. Will correct.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);
```